# update marker after checking database in x time by ajax does't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Here I am trying to update markers after 3 second from database, I am simply try to add marker at run time in google maps from a database without page loading. I think problem came in `<div>` tag, initially marker shows up but when ajax_call() came the page doesn't show anything. I am not a good programmer so help if you find any code mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script> 
       function ajax_call() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

        function initMap() {
                          // Create a map object and specify the DOM element      for display.
            var myLatLng = {center:new        google.maps.LatLng(31.55460609999999,74.35715810000001),
                               zoom: 13,
                                scrollwheel: true,
                                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID};  
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),  myLatLng);
             var all = <?php echo json_encode($jsArray) ?>;
            // Create a marker and set its position.
            for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
            {
                var myLatLng = {lat: all[i][2], lng: all[i][1]};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: myLatLng,
                    animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                    title: all[i][0]
                });
                   marker.setMap(map);}
            setInterval(ajax_call, 3000);
             }             

   </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCqGqkUbR3rvvo8QppeBBzRLUgEIduwmis&callback=initMap"
            async defer>

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and ajax.php code is:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT PhoneId, longitude, latitude FROM Clients";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$all = array();
$r = 0;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $c = 0;
        $all[$r][$c] = $row["PhoneId"];
        $c++;
        $all[$r][$c] = $row["longitude"];
        $c++;
        $all[$r][$c] = $row["latitude"];
        $r++;
    }
  $jsArray = array();
    foreach ($all as $array) {
        $jsArray[] = array($array[0], (double) $array[1], (double) $array[2]);
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();  ?> 
     <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <body>
    <script> 

 var all = <?php echo json_encode($jsArray) ?>;
            // Create a marker and set its position.
            for (i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
            {
                var myLatLng = {lat: all[i][2], lng: all[i][1]};
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: myLatLng,
                    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    title: all[i][0]
                });
                   marker.setMap(map);}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you do an ajax-call the output of the called script (ajax.php) will not get displayed in the browser and executed, but it will be returned as responseText. So you need to echo $jsArray in ajax.php and put the js from ajax.php into ajax_call() - of course with some adaptions, json_encode the output, JSON.parse the response, ...

Comment: Thanku Jeff, i appreciate your help.